# Calculate the thrust of a fan

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I'm having some difficulty with the following problem:

> The fan operating parameters are adjusted to reduce the constant negative pressure at the inlet ($p_\infty-\Delta p$) within a certain range of fans speed u. Calculate the thrust and drive power. $u$ and $\Delta p $ are given values. Picture below.

I'm wondering wether there are enough given parameters to solve the problem. Thrust is simply $\Delta p \cdot S$. I've tried using Bernoulli so as to calculate the relative speed v the observer moving with the fan would feel. ($u^2 + \cfrac{2\cdot\Delta p}{\rho} = v^2$). To determine $S$ it seems I'd need at least volumetric expenditure which wasn't given. Any hints are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/609954

Comment: @Solar Mike That's also my question. Actually, I've managed to solve that one. Now here I am stuck on another